# Trigonometry help about interval of $x/2$

Tags: trigonometry

If $x$ is element of $(3\pi/2, 2\pi)$, then $x/2$ is element of what interval?

Is this a valid question :) ?

Comment: $x \in \left({{3\pi}\over{2}}, 2\pi \right)$

$\implies \frac{x}{2} \in \left(\frac{1}{2}.{{3\pi}\over{2}}, \frac{1}{2}.2\pi \right)$

$\implies \frac{x}{2} \in \left({{3\pi}\over{4}},\pi \right)$

Comment: @Shuri2060 great. Thanks

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2):

$x \in \left({{3\pi}\over{2}}, 2\pi \right)$

By definition:

${{3\pi}\over{2}} < x < 2\pi$

$\implies {{3\pi}\over{4}} < \frac{x}{2} < \pi$

$\implies \frac{x}{2} \in \left({{3\pi}\over{4}},\pi \right)$

Comment: Damn I am silly ahah

Comment: This is a good idea.  Write it in terms of inequalities.  At leat at first. Even after you reach a point that you can do it without writing down anything, you will still be *thinking* of these inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

It's a valid question, but not well worded.  If $x$ is between $3\pi/2$ and $2\pi$, then certainly $x/2$ is between $3\pi/4$ and $\pi$.

Comment: I get it. Thanks :)